# Make sure user clicked my link through whatsapp

Tags: php, html, whatsapp

I want to build a PHP page and ask people to share my link through WhatsApp.

If user clicks my link through whatsapp, they will be able to see the page content.

If user clicks my link through LINE or Facebook Messenger or something else, they won't be able to see the page content.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: No its not possible but you can annoy them with  some   encryption .. but i see use of doing this .. its makes no sense imho

Comment: this is not possible because you have no control on whatsapp application , if you had you could add custom header to your request which then would be used to identify the request source (like whatsapp)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite tricky ! I did in my whatsapp bot application. ! It's quite tough but still one hope ! You can find whatsapp server ip from the android application code. 1st off all decode the whatsapp android application (current version) using [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). (apktool is not necessary). dex2jar will produce the .jar file of application. Open jar file by any jar-viewers and find server details in the code. (Lengthy Process)

After knowing that just create a function in your php script to get redirected URL details. either using [curl](http://wireshock.com/find-redirected-url-using-php-with-this-simple-function/) or [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

**Note: I didn't test it on iPhone / BB / Symbian devices. I am not sure about the efficiency of this trick ! You can give a try !**